# regarding Extjs Grid and preloading?

Tags: ajax, extjs, grid, preloading

I am having huge data, to display this I am using grid with paging enabled,
and loading the first page data.

How i can load the next page data in the back ground ??
so that when the user clicks next button I will show the data which is preloaded.

Any work around.

Thanks in advance,
kkchaitu

Comment: In short, you would have to extend the Pagination component and write another component for that, that manipulates the `Store` in the `GridPanel`. AFAIK this is impossible for the original Pagination component. I am not free now and if I have time I would write that for you. You can try yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution could be a loading whole set of data to the store and use Paginating Toolbar for filtering purpose, however you refering that amount of data is "huge" - this could make solution uneffective...

or

Have 3 set of data ready (before - empty at start, actual, and after) and overwrite onload events:

- after loading - display and load next, (or previous),
- before load check is next (or previous) is avaible - use it, change what is prevoius, actual, next, prepare what should be loaded after (in background)

keep in mind that Ajax requests are asinchronic and clicking could be faster than loading and this should be predicted in logic... However this is just an idea